# Handling async user events with React Testing Library, userEvent, and waitFor without triggering 'act' warnings

Tags: testing, jestjs

According to several other posts and documents, user events shouldn't wrapped in act and the proposed solution is to move the assertion into `waitFor` which I did. But if I do so, the assertion is triggered before the user events has been finished.

```js
it('test', async () => {
  render(<TestComponent />);

  const input = await screen.findByRole('textbox', { name: 'test' });
  const user = userEvent.setup();

  user.type(input, 'test');
  user.keyboard('{enter}');

  await waitFor(async () => {
    expect(input).toHaveDisplayValue('');
  });
});
```

To make it work, I can just add await in front of the user events like so:

```js
await user.type(input, 'test');
await user.keyboard('{enter}');
```

This works, but gives me the warning:

> Warning: An update to t inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

After wrapping the user events with `act` and using async (otherwise the assertion will run before the user events has taken place) I'm getting another warning:

> Warning: The current testing environment is not configured to support act(...)

```js
await act(async () => {
  await user.type(input, 'test');
  await user.keyboard('{enter}');
});
```

I've been trying all kinds of combination to get this to work but it's starting to get really frustrating and I can't seem to fix it. Can someone tell me what the proper way is to get this to work without getting those warnings?

I'd be nice if I don't have to add some hardcoded timeouts etc.